# Parsing strangely formatted xml with php

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

Here is a snippet of the xml, it is in a format I have never seen and for the life of me I can't figure out how to parse it into something that would actually look decent on a website. Here is the xml. It is a result of a search query on the shopping.com api.

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#14 (11) {
  ["@attributes"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(9) "101677489"
  }
  ["name"]=>
  string(26) "Nikon D3100 Digital Camera"
  ["shortDescription"]=>
  string(87) "14.2 Megapixel, SLR Camera, 3 in. LCD Screen, With High Definition Video, Weight: 1 lb."
  ["fullDescription"]=>
  string(829) "The Nikon D3100 digital SLR camera speaks to the growing ranks of enthusiastic D-SLR users and aspiring photographers by providing an easy-to-use and affordable entrance to the world of Nikon D-SLRâ€™s. The 14.2-megapixel D3100 has powerful features, such as the enhanced Guide Mode that makes it easy to unleash creative potential and capture memories with still images and full HD video. Like having a personal photo tutor at your fingertips, this unique feature provides a simple graphical interface on the cameraâ€™s LCD that guides users by suggesting and/or adjusting camera settings to achieve the desired end result images. The D3100 is also the worldâ€™s first D-SLR to introduce full time auto focus (AF) in Live View and D-Movie mode to effortlessly achieve the critical focus needed when shooting Full HD 1080p video."
  ["images"]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#4 (1) {
    ["image"]=>
    array(5) {
      [0]=>
      object(SimpleXMLElement)#13 (2) {
        ["@attributes"]=>
        array(3) {
          ["available"]=>
          string(4) "true"
          ["height"]=>
          string(3) "100"
          ["width"]=>
          string(3) "100"
        }
        ["sourceURL"]=>
        string(131) "http://di1.shopping.com/images/pi/93/bc/04/101677489-100x100-0-0.jpg?p=p2.6566ad68b022f6260efc&a=2&c=1&l=7000610&t=110528211343&r=2"
      }
      [1]=>
      object(SimpleXMLElement)#5 (2) {
        ["@attributes"]=>
        array(3) {
          ["available"]=>
          string(4) "true"
          ["height"]=>
          string(3) "200"
          ["width"]=>
          string(3) "200"
        }
        ["sourceURL"]=>
        string(131) "http://di1.shopping.com/images/pi/93/bc/04/101677489-200x200-0-0.jpg?p=p2.6566ad68b022f6260efc&a=2&c=1&l=7000610&t=110528211343&r=2"
      }
      [2]=>
      object(SimpleXMLElement)#12 (2) {
        ["@attributes"]=>
        array(3) {
          ["available"]=>
          string(4) "true"
          ["height"]=>
          string(3) "300"
          ["width"]=>
          string(3) "300"
        }
        ["sourceURL"]=>
        string(131) "http://di1.shopping.com/images/pi/93/bc/04/101677489-300x300-0-0.jpg?p=p2.6566ad68b022f6260efc&a=2&c=1&l=7000610&t=110528211343&r=2"
      }
      [3]=>
      object(SimpleXMLElement)#11 (2) {
        ["@attributes"]=>
        array(3) {
          ["available"]=>
          string(4) "true"
          ["height"]=>
          string(3) "400"
          ["width"]=>
          string(3) "400"
        }
        ["sourceURL"]=>
        string(131) "http://di1.shopping.com/images/pi/93/bc/04/101677489-400x400-0-0.jpg?p=p2.6566ad68b022f6260efc&a=2&c=1&l=7000610&t=110528211343&r=2"
      }
      [4]=>
      object(SimpleXMLElement)#10 (2) {
        ["@attributes"]=>
        array(3) {
          ["available"]=>
          string(4) "true"
          ["height"]=>
          string(3) "500"
          ["width"]=>
          string(3) "606"
        }
        ["sourceURL"]=>
        string(131) "http://di1.shopping.com/images/pi/93/bc/04/101677489-606x500-0-0.jpg?p=p2.6566ad68b022f6260efc&a=2&c=1&l=7000610&t=110528211343&r=2"
      }
    }
  }
  ["rating"]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#7 (4) {
    ["reviewCount"]=>
    string(1) "5"
    ["rating"]=>
    string(4) "5.00"
    ["ratingImage"]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#9 (2) {
      ["@attributes"]=>
      array(2) {
        ["height"]=>
        string(2) "18"
        ["width"]=>
        string(2) "91"
      }
      ["sourceURL"]=>
      string(48) "http://img.shopping.com/sc/pr/sdc_stars_sm_5.gif"
    }
    ["reviewURL"]=>
    string(61) "http://www.shopping.com/Nikon-D3100/reviews~linkin_id-7000610"
  }
  ["minPrice"]=>
  string(6) "519.00"
  ["maxPrice"]=>
  string(6) "712.00"
  ["productOffersURL"]=>
  string(60) "http://www.shopping.com/Nikon-D3100/prices~linkin_id-7000610"
  ["productSpecsURL"]=>
  string(58) "http://www.shopping.com/Nikon-D3100/info~linkin_id-7000610"
  ["offers"]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#6 (1) {
    ["@attributes"]=>
    array(3) {
      ["matchedOfferCount"]=>
      string(2) "10"
      ["pageNumber"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["returnedOfferCount"]=>
      string(1) "0"
    }
  }
```

Any ideas? I've tried the following code already but it doesn't change anything.

```
foreach( $xml->categories->category->items->product as $product )
{
var_dump($product);
}
foreach( $xml->categories->category->items->offer as $offer )
{
var_dump($offer);
}
```

Comment: The XML is already *parsed*. What's the problem you're having? *Extracting* the necessary information? Which information would that be then?

Comment: So it is parsed? Yes I want to extract the necessary information. This is the code I used to get the info

$x = file_get_contents($url);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($x);

foreach( $xml->categories->category->items->product as $product )
{
var_dump($product);
}
foreach( $xml->categories->category->items->offer as $offer )
{
var_dump($offer);
}

?>



I want to display each product with a price and a picture etc. From what I understand what is returned should look like this: http://sandbox.api.shopping.com/publisher/3.0/rest/GeneralSearch?apiKey=authorized-key&trackingId=7000610&keyword=nikon.

Comment: I'd recommend you read up on [var_dump](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) so you know what it's actually outputting...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like:

```
foreach( $xml->categories->category->items->product as $product )
{
    echo "{$product->name} from {$product->minPrice} to {$product->maxPrice}\n";
}
```

Comment: That works for part of what I want to do and I should be able to figure out the rest. So if I'm reading this right it reads through each product and echos the name, max, and min price?

Comment: @Ryan: Yes. Each sub-node can be accessed in a similar manner (e.g.: `$product->image[0]->sourceURL`). Note: If you find that answer useful, upvote it (or accept it if it solved your problem). :)